# How to maintain sessions for offline apps android

Tags: java, android

Is there a standard way of handling sessions for android applications where log in happens only once and and it remains offline most of the time except on sync? 
(For this use case we define an session as the launching and exit of the application. Session doesn't depend on the log in and log out )

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Shared Application Preferences in Android to maintain your Session Storage,
Here I am sharing a complete PreferenceHandler class I mostly use in android Applications,

```
public class PreferenceHelper {

    SharedPreferences preferences;
    Context context;
    Editor editor;
    public static final String PREFERENCES_NAME = "YourApplicationName";

    public PreferenceHelper(Context context) {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void addPreference(String key, String value) {
        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void addPreference(String key, Set<String> values) {
        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putStringSet(key, values);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void addPreference(String key, int value) {
        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void addPreference(String key, float value) {
        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putFloat(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void addPreference(String key, boolean value) {
        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void addPreference(String key, long value) {
        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putLong(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void editPreference(String key, String value) {
        editor = preferences.edit();
        if (preferences.contains(key)) {
            editor.remove(key);
        }
        addPreference(key, value);
    }

    public void editPreference(String key, Set<String> value) {
        editor = preferences.edit();
        if (preferences.contains(key)) {
            editor.remove(key);
        }
        addPreference(key, value);
    }

    public void editPreference(String key, int value) {
        editor = preferences.edit();
        if (preferences.contains(key)) {
            editor.remove(key);
        }
        addPreference(key, value);
    }

    public void editPreference(String key, float value) {
        editor = preferences.edit();
        if (preferences.contains(key)) {
            editor.remove(key);
        }
        addPreference(key, value);
    }

    public void editPreference(String key, boolean value) {
        editor = preferences.edit();
        if (preferences.contains(key)) {
            editor.remove(key);
        }
        addPreference(key, value);
    }

    public void editPreference(String key, long value) {
        editor = preferences.edit();
        if (preferences.contains(key)) {
            editor.remove(key);
        }
        addPreference(key, value);
    }

    public String getStringValue(String key) {
        String value = preferences.getString(key, "");
        return value;
    }

    public Set<String> getValues(String key) {
        Set<String> values = preferences.getStringSet(key, null);
        return values;
    }

    public int getIntValue(String key) {
        int value = preferences.getInt(key, -1);
        return value;
    }

    public boolean getBooleanValue(String key) {
        boolean value = preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
        return value;
    }

    public float getFloatValue(String key) {
        float value = preferences.getFloat(key, -1);
        return value;
    }

    public Long getLongValue(String key) {
        Long value = preferences.getLong(key, -1);
        return value;
    }

    public void removeKey(String key) {
        preferences.edit().remove(key);
        preferences.edit().commit();
    }

    public void clearAllPreferences() {
        preferences.edit().clear();
        preferences.edit().commit();
    }
}
```

To call and use this in your application simply make an object of this class,

```
PreferenceHelper preferences=new PreferenceHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

and if you are are using Segments or any other sub layout use this method,

```
PreferenceHelper preferences = new PreferenceHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

Following is an example of how I am using this as per for my login requirement

```
if (preferences.getBooleanValue("is_logged")) {
            preferences
                    .addPreference("last_login", DateHelper.getCurrentDate());
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
```

to set values in preferences I am using this method at Login time,
In Login method use this,

```
preferences.addPreference("is_logged", true);
preferences.addPreference("email", email);
preferences.addPreference("user_name", username);
preferences.addPreference("password", password);
preferences.addPreference("last_login",
DateHelper.getCurrentDate());
int uid = JsonHelper.getReturnID(result);
boolean is_admin, is_manager;
is_admin = JsonHelper.getBoolean(result, "is_admin");
is_manager = JsonHelper.getBoolean(result, "is_manager");
preferences.addPreference("is_admin", is_admin);
preferences.addPreference("is_manager", is_manager);
preferences.addPreference("uid", uid);
String phone, name;
phone = JsonHelper.getStringFromResult(result, "phone");
name = JsonHelper.getStringFromResult(result, "name");
preferences.addPreference("phone", phone);
preferences.addPreference("name", name);
startActivity(new Intent(StartingActivity.this,
MainActivity.class));
```

Hope this will solve your question.

Comment: thanks for the reply, was looking for if there's any standard way of creating session ids on the android app and then syncing it to the server.

Comment: There is no such standard method available in android till date. All you have to do is to handle your code manually.